# Autowiring Spring Bean that is a subclass of a different bean

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc

I have a Java 7/Spring MVC project I am working on right now. I have a class A. I want to test A's logic so I created a mock class called B, that extends A and picks up its protected methods.

I have an application-config.xml file and a unit-testing-config.xml
In the app-config I create a bean for A and set the beans id. In the unit-testing-config I override that definition with B.

I have logged which constructor gets called and it is A. But when I remove the extends part of B, and rerun, spring creates an instance of B. Is there a way to tell spring explicitly that I want the child to be instantiated. My definition looks like this:

```
<bean id="something" class="com.site.namespace.package.MockA" autowire="byName" />
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd have to specify an entirely new bean to test A's logic? We have a similar setup here at work and we just test the beans directly. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As I understood, you have same id for the bean in **application** & **unit-testing-config**. That means that the problem with the load, is most likely related to the order in which your xml configuration files loaded. If in first case **application-config.xml** was loaded last, A would override **unit-testing-config.xml** B definition, and otherwise. So you need to be sure, that you load your xml's in the same order, to get desired effect.
2. Have you worked with Spring profiles: https://spring.io/blog/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/ This is preferable way to do this kind of testing, with separate instances for testing and production environment. I would switch to profiles, and keep configurations in one place.

Comment: I do have the files loaded in the correct order. I will look into profiles. For now I have just refactored my code around the problem but thanks for the help. I will give you the cred anyways.

Answer (score 0):

[Spring Re-Inject](https://github.com/sgri/spring-reinject) can inject mocks without modification of XML files.